# Momentum conservation of a rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, relativity, relative-motion

I am trying to solve a relativistic rocket equation. The rocket dumbes fuel $N$ times, in the $-x$ direction, with a mass of $\varepsilon m_0$, where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the rocket. The rocket only moves in the $+x$ direction and initally its at rest. The question asks the final speed of the rocket.

Since initally the rocket at rest I wrote

$$\vec{p}^R_i = (m_0, 0,0,0)$$

and at final situation

$$\vec{p}^R_f = [m_0-\varepsilon m_0 N](\gamma, v\gamma, 0 ,0)$$
$$\vec{p}^F_f = [\varepsilon m_0 N](\gamma', -u\gamma', 0 ,0)$$

After equating them I get

$$1 = \gamma - \varepsilon N\gamma + \varepsilon N\gamma' $$
$$0 = v\gamma - \varepsilon N\gamma v - \varepsilon N\gamma'u$$

Where $v$ is the speed of the rocket, $u$ is the speed of the fuel, $\gamma = \gamma(v)$ and $\gamma' = \gamma(u)$.

Now the question has three parts

$(a)ε = 1/2, N = 1$
 $(b) ε = 1/4, N = 2 $
$(c) ε \ll 1, N \gg 1, εN = 1/2$

For me it seems all of them are equal. But I cannot be sure. Either they are indeed equal since in all cases $\varepsilon N = 1/2$, or I made a mistake in the calculations and they cannot be equal.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you wrote the momentum of fuel, it can be assumed that all the $\varepsilon m_0N$ of fuel is moving as one chunk with the velocity $-u$. However, in reality only the first chunk will move with $-u$, the next chunk will move with a different velocity, because the rocket wasn't stationary when it dumbed this chunk.